# Is there a way to determine if an argument is a method in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, methods

Is there any way to check if an argument passed into a function is a **method**?

For example, I want to determine inside a function if one of the inputs is a method or a stand-alone function:

```
function isMethod(collection, fct) {
  var isFct = (typeof fct === 'function');
  var isProperty = (collection.hasOwnProperty(fct)); // doesn't work b/c fct = object1.methodFct, not methodFct
  return `${isFct}, ${isProperty}`;
}

function nonMethodFct(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

var object1 = {
  methodFct(a, b) { 
    return a + b;
  }
};

console.log(typeof object1.methodFct === 'function' && object1.hasOwnProperty('methodFct')); // returns true

var expectTrueFalse = isMethod(object1, nonMethodFct); // returns true, false
console.log(expectTrueFalse);
var expectTrueTrue = isMethod(object1, object1.methodFct); // returns true, (false)
console.log(expectTrueTrue);
```

Since an input of `'methodFct'` returns an error for undefined (because `methodFct` is hidden inside the lexical scope of `object1`), I have to enter it in property accessor notation (`object1.methodFct`), which breaks the `isProperty` check inside the function.

In other words, I want to do what the independent `console.log()` does, but I don't know how to do it with an argument instead of a hard-coded string.

I played around with `JSON.stringify` and `.toString()` but they seemed to only stringify the entire contents of `collection` and `fct`, not their names.

Comment: The method `.hasOwnProperty()` expects a [string for an argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty); i.e. the name of the function you want to check for, not the function itself. To do that in your above code you can do the following `collection.hasOwnProperty(fct.name)` on line 3. Additionally you need to also check if that property is actually a function within the object; `typeof object1[fct.name] === 'function'` should do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `fct.name`

```js
function isMethod(collection, fct) {
    console.log(`fct.name = '${fct.name}'`);
    return (typeof collection[fct.name] === 'function');
}

function nonMethodFct(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

var object1 = {
    methodFct(a, b) { 
        return a + b;
    }
};


var expectFalse = isMethod(object1, nonMethodFct); // false
console.log(expectFalse);
var expectTrue = isMethod(object1, object1.methodFct); // true
console.log(expectTrue);
```